# javascript checkbox.checked always returns false

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

it might be a strange question, but I am unable to find a solution. Maybe i'm missing something or has done something incorrectly.

The issue is that the javascript function `.checked` always return false with **default checked element**. Here below is a HTML page, generated from a TWIG-template

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_1" name="call_1"  /><label for="cb_1">add call button</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_2" name="call_2" checked /><label for="cb_2">add call button</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_3" name="call_3" checked /><label for="cb_3">add call button</label>
```

twig template

```
{% for ins in instructions %}
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_{{ ins.step }}" name="call_{{ ins.step }}" {% if ins.callButton %}checked{% endif %} /><label for="cb_{{ ins.step }}">add call button</label>
{% endfor %}
```

( Please note that i have omitted other form entries )
The result of the above template is a form control with different boxes and the checkbox. The result is as follows

```
(1) [ ]
(2) [V]
(3) [V]
```

Now, let's say, I want to move the (2) to (1), that users can place the priority of (2) higher to (1). Moving the form content works as intented, but not the checkbox value itself. The result should be as follows

```
(1) [V]
(2) [ ]
(3) [V]
```

Here is my script function which handles the swap between two boxes.

```
// function to switch data, _cid = current index, _oid = other index
var switchFormData = function(_cid, _oid) {
    var tmp = $('cb_' + _cid).checked;
    $('cb_' + _cid).checked = $('cb_' + _oid).checked;
    $('cb_' + _oid).checked = tmp;
}
```

The other form data has been switched without problems. Only the checkbox check state doesn't.

But the irony is that `tmp` variable is always `false`, no matter of the checkbox state. I have checked with firebug if the `$('cb_' + _cid)` selector works (it's a getElementById shorthand) and it's displaying the right html element that i want to access to.

Now, the above solution works if use `$('cb_' + _cid).checked = true;` before it. Doubleclicking the checkbox didn't changed the result, still `false`.

Does anyone know why this happens, and how i can solve this ?
(and happy newyear for everyone)

**EDIT 1**

My excuses for confusing some people, but the above script is a pure js script. It's a very small script (replacing form data without changing the element id's), so i have decided to work without jQuery. the `$('cb_' + _cid)` method is a call to other function, here below. It returns with a HTML element.

```
// DGEBI shorthand
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};
```

- HTML5
- browser ; firefox 25.0.1

It seems that **my** browser is causing the issue here. (see comments of this post). I'm going to investigate it...

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: It looks like you're trying to access the `checked` property of a __jQuery object__ which of course does not exist. Try `.prop('checked')`.

Comment: And you are missing `#` in your selector. `$('cb_' + _cid)` should be `$('#cb_' + _cid)`

Comment: Does it happen only in a specific browser? I don't see anything obviously wrong (with the information you've provided).

Comment: This is working fine for me, in a simplified JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/dN6yW/

Comment: thanks for looking in this issue. Also my excuses for some confusion. I have added explanation. @ryanbrill : it appears that the problem persist on FF25.0.1. Even your JSFiddle didn't bring changes to the checkbox state.